# Get week number with week start day different than monday - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calendar, week-number

I want to get the week number of year associated with each date in IOS. I know I can get the ISO 8601 week number by using:

```
Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date())
```

But how to do it if the start day of a week could be any day of the week(like Sunday or Saturday)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your own `Calendar` with your own `firstWeekday`:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = someWeekdayYouLike
calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date())
```

If you want to use the first weekday of some `Locale`, set the `locale` of the calendar instead:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-gb")
print(calendar.firstWeekday) // 2
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-us")
print(calendar.firstWeekday) // 1
```